# Are there durable peel and stick tile options that can installed on the drywall above a vinyl shower/tub?

Tags: bathroom, tile

The drywall above the edge of the tub peels and cracks and I'm looking for options on how to protect it. I am comparing the cost, feasibility and appearance.

Comment: What is the source of the moisture? Is it from use of the shower/tub or is there a leak that must be addressed? Photo of area would be helpful. I would not install any peel and stick product for this application. The existing wall is degrading because of moisture and will continue unless addressed, so anything you stick to it will ultimately fail. A ceramic tile install would be best and is pretty simple. Any repair is contingent upon the source of the moisture established so that any fix will be permanent.

Answer (score 1):

A 6" [**peel and stick stone look**](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Aspect-24-in-x-6-in-Peel-and-Stick-Stone-Decorative-Backsplash-in-Medley-Slate-A90-81/207210210?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal2_rr-_-207211525-_-207210210-_-N) would be nice. Make sure everything is dry, scrape any loose paint off and clean the surface with some Tri-Sodium Phosphate to remove soap scum before applying the tiles. The tiles are easy to apply and easy to cut with common household tools. When you have all of the tiles installed, make sure to apply a bead of silicone caulking where the tile meets the tub and in the corners. You could use a color close to the tile color you choose in the corners first. Let that dry and then caulk the base with a white caulk for a clean uniform look. You might consider caulking across the top with the colored caulk if you are skilled at caulking. However, keep in mind that you can't touch up with paint as silicone caulk isn't paintable.

[image: Peel Stick Tile]

Comment: According to a question/answer in the link...that is REAL stone!